# is there a way to prevent others from changing data in a row in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm designing an application using mongodb and python and I need some way to read a row then based on its contents update it but I don't know of a way to make sure than another process isn't accessing that row also. My searched for 'locking a row in mongodb' don't return anything useful.

I'm currently accessing the data using:

```
row = db.table.find_one({'_id' : id})
if row['value'] > 10:
    db.table.save(update_row(row))
```

But I worry that between row being created and the updated record being saved the data could have been accessed.

What sort of design pattern should i be using

Comment: have you read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [JavaScript Code](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/) to update the document only if it is original as initially read. Sorry I'm not good with python but you could use this code as a starting point.